# Horizontal shear modelling

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-modeling

This week, my professor stated the image of Mona Lisa below has undergone a horizontal shear and the way to model this shear mathematically in 2 dimensions is to use the following sort of matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & a\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$

where $a$ is the shear factor. It has a single eigenvector, namely 1, and all eigenvectors corresponding to this single eigenvector have the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}k\\0 \end{pmatrix},$$

where $k≠0$

My question is, how would this be modelled mathematically in 3 or more dimensions? Would the matrix increase to a 3x3 matrix, and so on? Also, would you have any textbook recommendations which cover this topic?

[image]

Comment: When you say "how would this be modeled mathematically", what exactly do you mean by "this"?

Comment: This came about from a discussion on how eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be visualised. My professor told me the blue vector is an eigenvector, but the red one is not, because the transformed vector is not a scalar multiple of the original one. I just wanted to get a better idea on how horizontal shearing would appear in matrix format and how it can vary between 2 and 3 dimensions and so on. Sorry if I'm not clear on this.

Comment: I can't draw a picture, but the matrix corresponding to a horizontal (parallel to the $xy$ plane) shear along the vector $v = (v_1,v_2)$ is given by
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&av_1\\0&1&av_2\\0&0&1},
$$
where $a$ is, again, the shear factor.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks again Omnomnomnom.